# How do I take user inputs from a textfield and make them variables in a Google Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, scripting

This is the PARTIAL Google Scripts file.

**Code.gs**

CriteriaColumn, Choice1, Destination1, Choice2, Destination2 should be whatever the user entered in the HTML textfield.

```
  if (colIndex == CriteriaColumn && rowIndex != 1) {
```

Get value from column CriteriaColumn, in the active row.

```
    if (status == Choice1) {
```

The target sheet is named whatever Destination1 is.

```
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Destination1);
    }
    else if (status == Choice2) {
```

The target sheet is whatever Destination2 is.

```
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Destination2);
    }
```

This is the HTML file. Whatever is entered into the textfields should become variables in the Google Script.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
```

The text fields are below are entered by the user. They should become variables in the Google Script.

```
    <p>What is the criteria column? Use a number, not a letter. ie. A=1....Z=26<input type="text" name="CriteriaColumn"/></p>
    <p>Choice 1<input type="text" name="Choice1"/></p>
    <p>Choice 2<input type="text" name="Choice2"/></p>
    <p>Destination 1<input type="text" name="Destination1"/></p>
    <p>Destination 2<input type="text" name="Destination2"/></p>
```

Clicking save will save their settings and apply them to the corresponding variables in the Google Script.

```
    <p><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="google.script.host.close()" /></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form in your html. Then you have to put your input tags inside that form and send the form to your apps script function.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) you can check an example on how to do this. In this example a file input was used, but it would be similar for your input tags.

```
<body>
 <form>
   <p>What is the criteria column? Use a number, not a letter. ie. A=1....Z=26<input type="text" name="CriteriaColumn"/></p>
    <p>Choice 1<input type="text" name="Choice1"/></p>
    <p>Choice 2<input type="text" name="Choice2"/></p>
    <p>Destination 1<input type="text" name="Destination1"/></p>
    <p>Destination 2<input type="text" name="Destination2"/></p>

    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)" />
 </form>
</body>
```

"processForm" is the name of the function in the gs file, so you have to change it to the name of your function.

The parameter "this.parentNode" is making the reference to the parent of the button, which in this case is the form.

The function "withSuccessHandler" will execute the javascript function (javascript code in your html) that you give as parameter. In the example the function is "updateUrl".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I assign Choice1, Choice2, and so on as variables in my gs file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form in your HTML:

```
<form>
  <p>What is the criteria column? Use a number, not a letter. ie. A=1....Z=26<input type="text" name="CriteriaColumn"/></p>
  <p>Choice 1<input type="text" name="Choice1"/></p>
  <p>Choice 2<input type="text" name="Choice2"/></p>
  <p>Destination 1<input type="text" name="Destination1"/></p>
  <p>Destination 2<input type="text" name="Destination2"/></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close())processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
```

Then in your Google Apps Script file, you process the form like it's an object. The name of each value will equal the name that you assigned it in your HTML:

```
function processForm(form) {
  var destination1 = form.Destination1;
  var destination2 = form.Destination2;
  //etc......
  //do other things with your variables
}
```

It is important to remember that variable scope will apply, so that your form values will only be viewable to your `processForm()` function unless you pass them to another function.

I usually close my `processForm()` functions with a `return 200` so that the success handler will trigger and close your custom interface. I don't know if this is necessary or not, but it works and I have fewer problems with closing custom interfaces this way.

For more information, see the Google API reference on [client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: How do I store the variables from the form? Essentially I am trying to let the end user change the variable value.

Comment: In the second chunk of code above, your script gets the form from your UI. You access the form's attributes using the same names that you gave them in your HTML (i.e. in your script file, you would access the text box with the name `Destination1` in your script by calling `form.Destination1`. You use this to assign your variable in your script. If you want these values to be kept between usages, you will need to look into [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties). Does this help clarify?